# Conversion error while Kotlin enum to Postgres Enum while updating ENUM field

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

I am trying to test to update the record with type as PG enum and using corresponding Kotlin enum also as given below.

I am getting error when I use CAST `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to status_type`

and when I CAST then I get below error

```
ERROR: column "status" is of type status_type but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Below is the repository method.

```
    @Query(
        value = """
       UPDATE jobs SET status=CAST(:status AS status_type) WHERE id IN :jobIDs
    """,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun updateStatus(
        jobIDs: List<UUID>,
        status: JobStatus
    )
```

Corresponding Kotlin enum for the PG Enum type.

```
enum class JobStatus {
    PENDING, 
    EXHAUSTED,
    CREATED,
}
```

A Entity model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs", schema = "data")
@TypeDef(
    name = "status_type",
    typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType::class,
    defaultForType = JobStatus::class
)
data class JobMapping(
    ...

    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(type = "status_type")
    val status: JobStatus,

    ...
)
```

SQL side of it -

```
CREATE TYPE status_type AS ENUM(
    'PENDING',      -- still to process.
    'EXHAUSTED',    -- when retried for max duration.
    'CREATED'       -- remark is created, thus successful.
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs(
  ...

  status status_type NOT NULL,

  ...
);

I can save this Entity successfully through Hibernate `save` method but when I use `updateStatus` method given above in example I got the error.

I tried to try search through Stackoverflow but I only got the solution with number of Annotations, which I had already added.kotli
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue converted the repository method from native query to hibernate query (which means not using table name and column name but use model and field name in the query) as hibernate bypasses handleing type conversion for native query works, also I needed to add `@Modifying` and `@Transactional` annotations as the query is DML.

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(
        value = """
       UPDATE Job SET status=:status WHERE id IN :jobIDs
    """
    )
    fun updateStatus(
        @Param("jobIDs") jobIDs: List<UUID>,
        @Param("status") status: JobStatus
    )
```